# npm install fills node_module with unwanted packages

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, npm-install

I'm trying to install Grunt on a local project, when running

```
    npm install grunt-contrib-watch
```

results in:

```
    sass-test username$ npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
    sass-test@1.0.0 /Users/username/Documents/WEB-DEV/sass-test
    └─┬ grunt-contrib-watch@1.0.0 
      ├── async@1.5.2 
      ├─┬ gaze@1.0.0 
      │ └─┬ globule@0.2.0 
      │   ├─┬ glob@3.2.11 
      │   │ ├── inherits@2.0.1 
      │   │ └── minimatch@0.3.0 
      │   ├── lodash@2.4.2 
      │   └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14 
      │     ├── lru-cache@2.7.3 
      │     └── sigmund@1.0.1 
      ├── lodash@3.10.1 
      └─┬ tiny-lr@0.2.1 
        ├─┬ body-parser@1.14.2 
        │ ├── bytes@2.2.0 
        │ ├── content-type@1.0.2 
        │ ├── depd@1.1.0 
        │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.3.1 
        │ │ └── statuses@1.3.0 
        │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.13 
        │ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
        │ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
        │ ├── qs@5.2.0 
        │ ├─┬ raw-body@2.1.6 
        │ │ ├── bytes@2.3.0 
        │ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
        │ └─┬ type-is@1.6.13 
        │   ├── media-typer@0.3.0 
        │   └─┬ mime-types@2.1.11 
        │     └── mime-db@1.23.0 
        ├─┬ debug@2.2.0 
        │ └── ms@0.7.1 
        ├─┬ faye-websocket@0.10.0 
        │ └─┬ websocket-driver@0.6.5 
        │   └── websocket-extensions@0.1.1 
        ├── livereload-js@2.2.2 
        ├── parseurl@1.3.1 
        └── qs@5.1.0
```

Installing all of the above packages into the node_module folder while failing to install the grunt dependancy. If these packages are dependancies for some other installed module, is there a way to find out what this is?

I'm thinking I have perhaps edited the default packages config folder but I am not too confident with npm to know for sure.

does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies installed match exactly with what is shown on the [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-watch). Grunt isn't listed as a dependency.

Remember that Grunt is a task runner. It could conceivably run any task that you could add to your gruntfile, but those tasks don't need to know about Grunt itself.

Just install Grunt separately and you'll be good to go.